# Date time error while creating table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am getting an **date/time**  error while creating table in my sql ? how can i fix this?

```
create table ibi.stpl_toll_day_fare_fy_ex as
select 
cast(date_time as date) as calendar_date,
```

I get this error

> Error code :1292.incorrect datatime value.

Comment: Um...you're missing a `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the value in the date_time field of the existing table has the right data (if may have non relevant value to date)

Answer (score 0):

From clause missing. You can query as below:

Using temporary table for demo, you can use your table

```
create temporary table yourtable(date_time date);
insert into yourtable(date_time) values (now());

create table stpl_toll_day_fare_fy_ex as
select 
cast(date_time as date) as calendar_date from yourtable;

Select * from stpl_toll_day_fare_fy_ex;
```